Host: Manjaro, Guest: Artix Linux, Issue: No virtio internet/NAT connection on VM
Like the title says, for whatever reason my VM no longer connects to the host/internet.
An e1000e connection does work.
So the problem seems to be with virtio?
On host:
ip a
...
4: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:8c:9c:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: vnet4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master virbr0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:8d:cd:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe8d:cd66/64 scope link proto kernel_ll 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

sudo virsh net-dumpxml default
<network connections='1'>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>b728bff2-6215-4472-8d38-a5a797d328aa</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:8c:9c:74'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>

On guest:
virt-manager connection config in xml
<network connections="1">
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>b728bff2-6215-4472-8d38-a5a797d328aa</uuid>
  <forward mode="nat">
    <nat>
      <port start="1024" end="65535"/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name="virbr0" stp="on" delay="0"/>
  <mac address="52:54:00:8c:9c:74"/>
  <ip address="192.168.122.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
    <dhcp>
      <range start="192.168.122.2" end="192.168.122.254"/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>

ip a

network device
<interface type="network">
  <mac address="52:54:00:8d:cd:66"/>
  <source network="default" portid="94cebc1a-2b7b-41ba-91a4-22958fe3aef4" bridge="virbr0"/>
  <target dev="vnet4"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>


Check the firewall on the host. Consider adding iptables-save and nft list ruleset to your post.

Solved by manually editing "virtio" to "virtio-net" at the network device in xml.
For some reason virt-manager only gives me two options for models.

First disconnect from the internet by the disconnect option if available.
Then run this command in your VM :
sudo dhclient eth0
When I had installed Kali Linux for the first time, I was also unable to connect my VM to the internet, despite trying all the available options for network adapters in Oracle VirtualBox. Later on, when I started learning about it, I came to know about this command, and I was able to connect Kali to the internet.
Let me know if this works.

I've checked. dhclient is not installed on my VM. I have connman instead. I'll try and figure out how connman handles DHCP.

Okay, then I think you will need to run this commands.

sudo systemctl start connman        >>To start connman
connmanctl services                        >>To enlist the services available.
sudo connmanctl connect <service_name>       >>Replace with the actual service name that can be used to connect the VM to the internet.
Hope this works!

sudo dinitctl status connmand shows that my network connection service has started and is working.

Have you connected with any network interfaces available via: sudo connmanctl connect <service_name>? If yes, try ping 8.8.8.8 and see the results.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/i.snag.gy/QHAqJ2.jpg

I see... Then I think you have to disconnect once by the command-line interface and then reconnect. When I initially start my kali linux and try to directly connect by dhclient, it doesn't works. I need to disconnect and then reconnect. Idk why it happens with my VM, and proabaly it happens here.

Are you able to connect o the internet?

With my host? yes.

I can also connect to the internet with my VM using the outdated e1000e connection. But the modern virtio does not work.
